# Visualizing higher dimension

Tags: spacetime-dimensions, perception, visualization

Why can't we visualize Higher dimensions greater than 3? Is it just because the dimensions doesn't exist (Certainly I know that space-time is four dimensional) or any other physical reasons.

Comment: This is an issue with human psychology. There is nothing wrong with higher dimensional spaces. We simply have not evolved the capability to picture them the way we can 3D space.

Comment: What's your definition of "visualize"? If you mean "portray higher-dimensional space in such a way that movement within it is comprehensible and somewhat intuitive," then we can definitely do so. See e.g. 3Blue1Brown's video on the subject: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zwAD6dRSVyI

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/188717/2451 More on [visualization of higher dimensions](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/visualization+spacetime-dimensions).

Comment: I mean to imagine.

Comment: @walber97 It's still not entirely clear to me what counts as "imagination" in this case. If I watch the 3Blue1Brown video and mentally replay it in my head, with some slight variations, am I now imagining higher dimensions? If not, why not? In other words, what's stopping me from taking the intuitive representation of higher dimensions provided in that video and using that as the definition of how I visualize higher dimensions in my imagination?